# Return formatted time from database or model in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm storing time in a Mysql database, and by default it stores in the format 00:00:00

I'm using this to retrieve it:

```
public function events(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
}

$events = $user->events()->orderBy('time')->get();
```

Now the problem is that I want to return it without the seconds, just in 00:00 format. Is there a laravel way to convert this easily without having to create a loop and convert each record manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think u just need to define an accessor for this field

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

like this (in your user model)

```
public function getTimeAttribute($value)
{
    $time = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $value);

    return $time->format('H:i');
}
```

Comment: It should be `getTimeAttribute`. This is an accessor.

Comment: love it @M0rtiis .. how about a faster way? return substr($value, 0, -3);

Comment: substr thats another "logic". not related to time. bad way for laravel